# Google Maps API area search

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a set of adresses / coordinates. In my software the user should be able to search for a specific adress or coordinate and find the surrounding places of the set of coordinates in a specific radius. The results should be shown on a map.
(Mostly like Google Places for Restaurants just with my own set of places)
Displaying the places on a static map is not the problem, but handling the set of addresses (~5000) and calculating the distances to the place searched for.

How can I establish a function like this using Google's APIs?

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried ? show us your codes . which programming language are you using ?

Comment: sry should have added this. I am working with PHP. The only thing i am doing right now is comparing the adresses of the search with the stored adresses. I am a bit scarred of comparing the coordinates of each entry and calculating the distance. I hope there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the harvesine formula and a bounding box. Or you can use a spatial index and a bounding box. The harvesine formula is used for spheres. Most likely you use straight distance (like the crow flies).